# Problem with publishing my first post properly

Tags: discussion

I am posting my fist question here and  have made many mistakes so far so I have ended up with more than one post (I don't really understand how many) about the same question.

I don't know how to delete 'duplicates' and would like to keep the last posted version which is
[How to figure out the necessary boot parameters to boot an iso file from a multiboot usb driver?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/732641/how-to-figure-out-the-necessary-boot-parameters-to-boot-an-iso-file-from-a-multi)

Excuse me for causing trouble.

Comment: There should be a delete-link below each of your posts. Using that, you should be able to delete your [previous post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/732625/) and this post. Or a moderator can help you. All good.

Comment: @ Freddy : Many Thanks!